# parametrizing dataset into normal distribution for simulation and dealing with an impossible negative values

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, monte-carlo

I am trying to simulate the production based on the historical data of the ratio between production planning vs realization. I have some doubt regarding my distribution, here are what I did so far:

the data was given by this distribution:

[image: historical data]
with n=315, mean=1.03 std=0.52

I cut the outlier at 1.5IQR so the distribution looked this:

[image: data without outlier]
with n=299, mean=0.80 std=0.38

then I create 1000 random normal values based on the previous mean and std

[image: random normal values]
n=1000 mean=0.80 std=0.36

as you can there are some negative values on the resulting distribution which is impossible in real situation.

as far as I understand, I have two option to dealing with this negative values, which is just drop it, or drag it to 0

[image: distribution where the negative values are dropped]
n=987 mean=0.82 std=0.35

[image: distribution where the negative values dragged to 0]
n=1000 mean=0.81 std=0.36

so in conlusion my question are:
1. Is it right for me to model it with normal distribution?
2. Which is the best practice to dealing with the negative values?(I know in this case the results of both are not that far off, but I need to do this with a lot of other dataset, and some of it seems to have lower mean and larger std which I think would give me a lot more negative values.)

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. My blog post [how to ask a statistics question](https://statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/) may help you formulate it so it can be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, cutting out the "outlier" to better fit a model is wrong. Second, your data is non-negative, so you need a non-negative distribution. Normal distribution is not appropriate, Gamma would be the next choice.

Or you could use a more non-parametric version like rejection sampling to sample from arbitrary distributions.

Comment: I fell that I need to cut the outlier because in this case I dont want to risk that small change where I would get that unusually large number and end up overestimating the forecast. The unusually large rations after all are unacceptable and most likely are the results of a bad recording/miscalcullation. In regards of the gamma and and rejection-sampling, I think those are some more applicable alternative and I will look more about that. If I ended up using those distribution do you think that my reasons to cut outliers still acceptable?

Comment: @MuhamadNasirLukman If you have good reason to believe that those observations are wrong or of no interest then yes, you can remove them. I don't know what software you are using, but in R you can fit Gamma just as easily as normal.

Comment: at the moment i'm using python, but in the end I have to find a way to do it in excel. Thanks for the response.